# How can I fire a Javascript function and receive it in a Web Browser?

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to fire a Javascript function and receive the result in a web browser?

For example:

I have a website with Javascript. My web browser source goes there. When I execute something, the web browser should receive it automatically. Like the opposite of `InvokeScript()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an instance of a class with public methods that you want to call from your Javascript, you need to include it is as an object for scripting for your WebBrowser control.

```
wbMainBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new MyWindowsClass();
```

Now if your class had a method, `DoSomething();`, in your javascript you would do

```
window.external.DoSomething();
```

You can also pass inputs and recieve values from these methods.